# How do I grep on a live log (stdout)?

Tags: terminal, grep, stdout

I'm not sure if that what stdout is, but that's what I think.

What I want to do is  filter out a certain log message when running an executable.

I tried this:

```
Executable 2>&1 /dev/null | grep -v "fixme:quartz:Parser_OutputPin_QueryInterface No interface for {56a868a5-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770}!"
```

And a normal:

```
Executable | grep -v "fixme:quartz:Parser_OutputPin_QueryInterface No interface for {56a868a5-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770}!"
```

But the Terminal was still filled with thousands of `fixme:quartz` etc. messages.

Comment: It might be writing directly to `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Is this giving any output? `Executable > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to find out whether the messages you want are getting sent to stdout or stderr. In your first example, you've got stderr getting redirected to stdout - that's the "2>&1" part. You also have "/dev/null" on the command line, which doesn't entirely make sense.  Why does "/dev/null" appear on command line?

Second, you need to decide what message(s) you want to see. The "-v" flag to `grep` is going to *invert* the match - only lines that don't match your pattern string will get printed. The pattern you're specifying is pretty precise: you may need to try a less-specific pattern, like `'fixme:quartz'`, which by virtue of its shorter length, will cause `grep -v` to not match more lines.

If I were you, I'd do something like this:

```
Executable > log 2> err
```

That separates stdout and stderr into two different files. If I wanted to find the string "fixme:quartz", I'd do:

```
grep 'fixme:quartz' log
grep 'fixme:quartz' err
```

to decide which file to look at at, and then use a text editor that supports regular expressions (like `vim`) to find what I wanted.

If that doesn't work, or if `Executable` is supposed to run a long time, and you just want to see particular messages, do the above procedure, and determine your regular expression using `vim`, and figure out if the message is on stdout or stderr.  Then you can do this:

```
Executable > log 2> err
tail -f log | grep 'fixme:quartz'  # or whatever regular expression
```

As `Executable` runs and produces messages, `tail -f` will periodically read them from file "log" and print to its own stdout, where `grep` will filter for you.

Comment: "But the Terminal was still filled with thousands of fixme:quartz etc" - it seems OP is trying to filter out that line, so `-v` is appropriate.

Comment: @muru - good point, I read it wrong the first time through. I've changed my "grep -v" paragraph to indicate maybe how to fix that problem.

Comment: The reason I used the command I used (`/dev/null`) etc. was because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841)

Comment: @DisplayName - to do that that answer wanted, you need to put a '>' (right angle bracket, or "less than") sign before the /dev/null file name.